# How to implement CRC using C language

Tags: c, algorithm, implementation, crc

I am bit new to programming and i want to send a float data to eeprom from a controller and i want to implement **crc** for the error detection of the data when ever i tries to read or write.
This is my intention.But i found many algorithms for implementing crc and its been quite confusing for me to follow which one.
The compiler provides 4 bytes of space for all data and  its function sends each byte one at a time.So i trust i would be required to do the crc of each 8bit data or can implement it as a whole.
And i am using C language.

In brief:
i just need to do a 
1.Crc implementation.
2.Common Data size =32 bits
3.Compiler function  sends one byte at a time.
4.And how do we fix which algorithm to go for.

Thank you very much

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 3):

Try Reading this article(It Contains C Codes and Diagrams Which you need) :

http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/CRC-Calculation-C-Code

CRCs are among the best checksums available to detect and/or correct errors in communications transmissions. Unfortunately, the modulo-2 arithmetic used to compute CRCs doesn't map easily into software. This article shows how to implement an efficient CRC in C.

Comment: Also try this : CRC Implementation Code in C/C++